# DocuSign Envelope View for non authorized users

Tags: docusignapi

Can I provide public link for envelope view for not authorized users.

They have to see this page https://demo.docusign.net/Member/DocuSign.aspx?ti=...

Screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaUjT.png

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your use case, but you may want to read about DocuSign PowerForms if you want your users to be able to self serve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible to allow non-authorized users to view your envelopes.  These are usually private data and might contain sales numbers, prices, etc. - basically whatever document info that was signed.

Even recipients of a given envelope still have to authenticate to view the envelope, using email as the most basic form of authentication but potentially including things like access codes, RSA ID checks, etc.

For more info please see the [DocuSign Developer Center](http://www.docusign.com/developer-center)